# App crash on E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

There are many Q&A's on StackOverflow concerning the *"Error opening trace file"* error message. But it looks like my case is different.

**My App crashes when this error-message appears.**

Here is the logcat:

```
03-06 20:07:35.142 3033-16751/? W/photo.fastid.printservice.utilities.DownloadFile: Starting download......from https://example.com/download
03-06 20:07:37.052 3033-16775/? W/photo.fastid.printservice.utilities.DownloadFile: Starting download......from https://example.com/download
03-06 20:07:38.622 16792-16792/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-06 20:07:38.832 16792-16792/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-06 20:07:38.832 16792-16792/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-06 20:07:40.402 545-2066/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1162 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onVideoPlayerCrashed:3689 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked:3719 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked:4887 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked:4696
```

- The App polls a server for a (photo) download and has been doing this for a couple of hours.
- Then, Logcat shows the *"Error opening trace file"* message.
- After this message, my app no longer polls the server.
- However, other activities on the UI (like opening a menu or changing a setting) work fine.

There is nothing else in the logcat, no exceptions and print-stacks...

My questions:

- How is the polling related to this error?
- What can I do to get my polling stable again?

Note: this App is old but the error is new. Meanwhile, the code has not (significantly) changed. Can this be caused by AndroidStudio updating my SDK?

My gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "openbook.pub.photosprint"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never truly resolved this issue, but after adding

```
<application 
    android:largeHeap=["true"]
    . . .
</application>
```

to the Manifest, I have not seen this crash re-occur...